# Shibboleth Proxy to Azure AD Validation Error on redirect with error XML element 'RequesterID' in XML namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, shibboleth

I configured my local shibboleth IdP to proxy authentication to Azure AD but on redirect and getting an Azure error:

```
AADSTS7500522: XML element 'RequesterID' in XML namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' in the SAML message must be a URI.
```

My service provider that is redirecting to Shibboleth > AzureAD uses an entity ID that is just a name and not a URL which is what shows up in my saml trace back to Azure.

```
<saml2p:Scoping>
        <saml2p:RequesterID>EntityIDShortName</saml2p:RequesterID>
</saml2p:Scoping>
```

Is there a way to turn off this validation in Azure or transform / not include the requester id from shibboleth to Azure AD?

I used this document to do the configuration:
https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/1467056889/Using+SAML+Proxying+in+the+Shibboleth+IdP+to+connect+with+Azure+AD

Thanks
Nick

Comment: how about you change it to a URL like format (it does not have to be an actual URL)

Comment: Yeah, am going to do that.  problem is, the entityID from the metadata is actually set to a name not a URL so if I change it, will have to make sure I trickle that down.

Comment: FYI, changing to url did work for the azure validation. Would be nice to see if this can be disabled but is working.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, just changing the entity I’d in my test provider addresses this issue.